# Can't display database data in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on library website in which I want to display data from database which is Book name and description. But I'm not able to do that.  Here is my code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
def index(request):
   book_list = Book.objects.all()
   return render(request,template_name='index.html', context={'book_list':book_list})
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block new_books %}
{% for b in book_list %}
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src=".." alt="Image">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ book_list }} </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Hello this is card text</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">View this book</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should work with `b` variable instead of `book_list` inside of `for` loop.

If your `Book` model contains `title` field, your code might look like this:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block new_books %}
{% for b in book_list %}
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src=".." alt="Image">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ b.title }} </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Hello this is card text</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary">View this book</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```